# MPI - Issue with column type in language C

Tags: c, openmpi

I have a problem with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` communication where I send column from a process and received by another one.

For debugging, I show you below a basic example where I initialize a 10x10 matrix (`x0` array) with `x_domain = 4` and `y_domain = 4`. For the test, I simply initialize the 2D array values with `x0[i][j] = i+j`.

Could you try please to compile and execute the following test code wich simply sends a column from the `rank=2` and received by `rank=0` (you need to execute it with `nproc=4`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
      /* size of the discretization */

      double** x;
      double** x0;
      int bonk1, bonk2;      
      int i,j,k,l;
      int nproc;
      int ndims; 
      int S=0, E=1, N=2, W=3;
      int NeighBor[4];
      int xcell, ycell, size_tot_x, size_tot_y;
      int *xs,*ys,*xe,*ye;
      int size_x = 4;
      int size_y = 4;
      int me;
      int x_domains=2;
      int y_domains=2;
      int flag = 1;      
      MPI_Comm comm, comm2d;
      int dims[2];
      int periods[2];
      int reorganisation = 0;
      int row;
      MPI_Datatype column_type;
      MPI_Status status;


      size_tot_x=size_x+2*x_domains+2;
      size_tot_y=size_y+2*y_domains+2;

      xcell=(size_x/x_domains);
      ycell=(size_y/y_domains);

      MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
      comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
      MPI_Comm_size(comm,&nproc);
      MPI_Comm_rank(comm,&me);

      x = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));
      x0 = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));


      for(j=0;j<=size_tot_y-1;j++) {
        x[j] = malloc(size_tot_x*sizeof(double));
        x0[j] = malloc(size_tot_x*sizeof(double));
      }

      xs = malloc(nproc*sizeof(int));
      xe = malloc(nproc*sizeof(int));
      ys = malloc(nproc*sizeof(int));
      ye = malloc(nproc*sizeof(int));

      /* Create 2D cartesian grid */
      periods[0] = 0;
      periods[1] = 0;

      ndims = 2;
      dims[0]=x_domains;
      dims[1]=y_domains;

      MPI_Cart_create(comm, ndims, dims, periods, reorganisation, &comm2d);

      /* Identify neighbors */
      NeighBor[0] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
      NeighBor[1] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
      NeighBor[2] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
      NeighBor[3] = MPI_PROC_NULL;

      /* Left/West and right/Est neigbors */
      MPI_Cart_shift(comm2d,0,1,&NeighBor[W],&NeighBor[E]);
      /* Bottom/South and Upper/North neigbors */
      MPI_Cart_shift(comm2d,1,1,&NeighBor[S],&NeighBor[N]);

      /* coordinates of current cell with me rank */

      xcell=(size_x/x_domains);
      ycell=(size_y/y_domains);

      ys[me]=(y_domains-me%(y_domains)-1)*(ycell+2)+2;
      ye[me]=ys[me]+ycell-1;

      for(i=0;i<=y_domains-1;i++) 
      {xs[i]=2;}

      for(i=0;i<=y_domains-1;i++) 
      {xe[i]=xs[i]+xcell-1;}

      for(i=1;i<=(x_domains-1);i++)
         { for(j=0;j<=(y_domains-1);j++) 
              {
               xs[i*y_domains+j]=xs[(i-1)*y_domains+j]+xcell+2;
               xe[i*y_domains+j]=xs[i*y_domains+j]+xcell-1;
              }
         }

      for(i=0;i<=size_tot_y-1;i++)
          { for(j=0;j<=size_tot_x-1;j++)
            { x0[i][j]= i+j;
        }       
      }

      /*  Create column data type to communicate with South and North neighbors */



      MPI_Type_vector( ycell, 1, size_tot_x, MPI_DOUBLE, &column_type);  
      MPI_Type_commit(&column_type);

       if(me==2) {
       printf("Before Send - Process 2 subarray\n");
                    for(i=ys[me]-1;i<=ye[me]+1;i++)
                    { for(j=xs[me]-1;j<=xe[me]+1;j++)
                      { printf("%f ",x0[i][j]);
                      }
                      printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");



       MPI_Send(&(x0[ys[2]][xs[2]]), 1, column_type,  0, flag, comm2d );
       }

         if(me==0) {

     MPI_Recv(&(x0[ys[0]][xe[0]]), 1, column_type,  2, flag, comm2d , &status);
     printf("After Receive - Process 0 subarray\n");
                    for(i=ys[me]-1;i<=ye[me]+1;i++)
                    { for(j=xs[me]-1;j<=xe[me]+1;j++)
                      { printf("%f ",x0[i][j]);
                      }
                      printf("\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n");

        MPI_Get_count(&status,column_type,&bonk1);
        MPI_Get_elements(&status,MPI_DOUBLE,&bonk2);
        printf("got %d elements of type column_type\n",bonk1);
        printf("which contained %d elements of type MPI_DOUBLE\n",bonk2);
    printf("\n");

         }

              for(i=0;i<=size_tot_y-1;i++)
           {
            free(x[i]);
            free(x0[i]);
           }     

        free(x);
        free(x0);

        free(xs);
        free(xe);
        free(ys);
        free(ye);

        MPI_Finalize();

        return 0;
    }
```

`xs[me]` and `xe[me]` correspond respectively to `x_start[me]` and `x_end[me]` of `rank = me`. This is the same for `ys[me]` and `ye[me]`.

As I said in the precedent post, there's only the first value of the column which is received by process of rank `0`. Here's the output of this program:

```
Before Send - Process 2 subarray
10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000
11.000000 **12.000000** 13.000000 14.000000
12.000000 **13.000000** 14.000000 15.000000
13.000000 14.000000 15.000000 16.000000

After Receive - Process 0 subarray
6.000000 7.000000 8.000000 9.000000
7.000000 8.000000 **12.000000** 10.000000
8.000000 9.000000 **10.000000** 11.000000
9.000000 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000

got 1 elements of type column_type
which contained 2 elements of type MPI_DOUBLE
```

---

I get `12.00000` for the first element but for the second element, I have `10.00000` instead of `13.00000`.

I defined `column_type` by:

```
MPI_Type_vector( ycell, 1, size_tot_x, MPI_DOUBLE, &column_type); 
MPI_Type_commit(&column_type);
```

`size_tot_x` is equal to the total number of columns of the global array `x0`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I recommend reading http://sscce.org/. Make a _minimal_ example that have the problem you are having. Start with the basics, then add one little bit, and then another little bit, and so on. In the end you will probably find the error yourself, and if not you have something smaller, simpler and more easy to follow to post here.

Comment: MPI **does not** support multidimensional arrays organised as arrays of pointers. Change your 2D arrays to have flat structure, i.e. `double *x = malloc(size_tot_x*size_tot_y*sizeof(double));`

Answer (score 0):

It's not an MPI issue but rather an issue in how you allocate the arrays in memory.

Basically there are two "schools of thought" when it comes to allocating 2- and higher dimensional arrays. The old school that MPI also follows uses flat arrays - rows are located one after another in the memory. This is how the compiler lays out an explicitly shaped array in memory, e.g. `double x[4][4]` would have the following layout:

```
x[0][0] x[0][1] x[0][2] x[0][3] x[1][0] x[1][1] ... x[3][2] x[3][3]
```

With such a layout the distance (in number of elements) between `x[i][k]` and `x[i+1][k]` is exactly equal to the number of elements in the row, that is `4` in this case. When you construct a dervied vector datatype in MPI with a block length of `1` and a stride of `4`, when used to send or receive data it will use elements that are in the same column.

A drawback of this model is that when one allocates memory dynamically, one has to explicitly compute offsets inside the array using something like `x[4*i+k]` instead of simply `x[i][k]`.

The second school of thought uses an array of pointers to each row and then allocates each row separately. This mechanism is nice as it allows "jagged" arrays to be constructed and also allows for the `x[i][k]` syntax to be used, but it **does not** guarantee that consequitive rows would be adjacent in memory, i.e. `x[i]` and `x[i+1]` might point to locations that are more than `4` elements apart.

What you should do is either switch your logic to use flat arrays or you could use a hybrid model - have a flat array allocated by `malloc()` and then create a row index:

```
double** x;
double** x0;

x = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));
x0 = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));

for(j=0;j<=size_tot_y-1;j++) {
  x[j] = malloc(size_tot_x*sizeof(double));
  x0[j] = malloc(size_tot_x*sizeof(double));
}

...

for(i=0;i<=size_tot_y-1;i++)
{
  free(x[i]);
  free(x0[i]);
}     

free(x);
free(x0);
```

should become

```
double* x_vals;
double** x;
double* x0_vals;
double** x0;

x_vals = malloc(size_tot_x*size_tot_y*sizeof(double));
x0_vals = malloc(size_tot_x*size_tot_y*sizeof(double));

x = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));
x0 = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(double*));

for(j=0;j<=size_tot_y-1;j++) {
  x[j] = &x_vals[j*size_tot_x];
  x0[j] = &x0_vals[j*size_tot_x];
}

...

free(x);
free(x_vals);
free(x0);
free(x0_vals);
```

I hope the difference between your code and what I propose is cleary visible.